# why my mac terminal auto complete always append $'\r' to the host name while i am using ssh config?

Tags: macos, ssh, terminal, autocomplete

[my terminal snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g0IRz.png)

```bash
the auto complete always looks like this =>ssh dev$'\r'

My ssh config:
Host dev
HostName xxxxx
User xxxx
Port xxxx
```

i'm using oh-my-zsh, I have to delete the appendix $'\r' by myself every time. i googled a lot but i didn't find the proper answer.

Answer (score 2):

The reason is my ./ssh/config is using CRLF mode. After i change CRLF to LF mode, it's fixed.